# Preventing Overwriting Deployments using Artifactory

Tags: artifactory

I have setup an instance of Artifactory (4.1.2) which I am using to store java artefacts. I push artifacts to the instance using the gradle plugin configured as below

```
artifactory {
    contextUrl = 'http://example.com/artifactory'
    publish {
        repository {
            // The Artifactory repository key to publish to
            repoKey = 'libs-release-local'

            username = artifactory_username
            password = artifactory_password
        }
        defaults {
            publications('releaseJar')
        }
    }
}
```

I want to be able to prevent overwriting already deployed artefacts by version. This seems to be a common request and the [docs](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Managing+Permissions) say

> You can prevent a user or group from overwriting a deployed release or unique snapshot by not granting the Delete permission. Non-unique snapshots can always be overwritten (provided the Deploy permission is granted).

However, I have set up a `deploy` user which is in groups `1 | deployers`
 with related permissions `1 | CanDeploy`.

The `CanDeploy` permission has `Deploy/Cache` permissions for the `deployers` group only.

However! I can overwrite the deployed artifact to my hearts content using `gradle artifactoryPublish`.

Any advice would be gratefully received :)

**EDIT:** Since asking this question the functionality has started working as desired. This is very weird as I had not changed the Artifactory settings at all but is now returning a `403` when I try to upload an artifact with the same version num as is already deployed. I can only presume there is something weird regarding caching of access permissions or something which resulting in my changes via the web UI not becoming effective for a day or two - unnerving but its currently working. Will leave question up for the moment while I ensure its working!

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to check the permissions are set is in the "Effective Permissions" tab in the browser UI.
When selecting the "releaseJar" repo, if you see the "delete" permission checked on the "deploy" user than you may have another permission target giving the delete permission to this user.
You can see the list of permission target used by a single user in the "Users" page.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Thx for the reply - the deploy user only as the `Deploy/Cache` perm checked. However this has now started working. Please see edit on question.